# Why the default standard size for the layout of webpages is 1024x768?

Tags: layout, web, size, resolution

I have been visiting websites and developing some and till now i don't know why the default size of the layout of those webpages is 1024x768. In other words, why they are neglecting the other parts of the screen? Why don't they develop the pages according to a high large resolution like 1920x2120 for example?

I have visited most websites around the web from Yahoo.com to Pepsi.com and all of them are placing those right and left margins eating half of the screen to fit their elements on a stage of 1024x768.

Is it because they need to open those website on mobile devices? or there is a more deep technical reason for that?

Comment: Q: Even if you preferred a football field of a monitor (and personally, I don't) ... then why would you want to waste all of that real estate with a stupid single web page?  Wouldn't you just make your browser one (of several) windows on your desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason is that people want more and more people to access their website. Almost 10 years ago, 1024x768 was the most common display resolution. After that while new and higher resolution displays have come in, there has not been a significant jump in the vertical resolution (768) of low end devices. Even now (beginning of 2012) almost 50% displays use max 800p as the vertical resolution.

So 1024x768 is a standard minimum resolution for which people design websites. There are high chances that if you design for wider/bigger resolutions, people using these devices may not see them on the top of their screen (without scrolling) and the content may remain unnoticed.

Check this wikipedia link for more detailed stats
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

To answer the other question, why not have multiple versions? Two reasons mainly:

1. Many websites actually are dynamically scalable. Check facebook or google images for example. Depending on your screen resolution they use the extra area to fit in extra content. This strategy generally suits websites that have blocks of content that can be fit in dynamically.
2. There are studies that suggest that for optimal and quick reading around 6-7 words or 500px (not exact numbers) is the best width. Anything more than that causes too much horizontal span and decreases reading speed. This affects the resolution of websites that are more about text for e.g. blogs and news websites.

Comment: Those were quite good reasons indeed. (+1)

Comment: I added a few more points about having multiple versions. Might be a useful read.

Comment: You nailed great reasons up there. Thanks "Chirag"! [Accepted]

Answer (score 1):

Twenty years ago, the general "standard" for GUI applications was 640x480.

Personally, I seldom run any of my displays over 1280x1024.  At the moment, I'm using two displays.

There really has to be *some* "least common denominator".  And, for no particularly good (or bad) reason, for the moment it happens to be 1024x768.

IMHO ... PSM

PS:

Here's a good table.  It's 5++ years old ... but probably still pretty accurate.  Especially given the increasing importance of smart phone displays over the last five years:

http://magiclamp.net/?PageID=102

```
Date Range                    April 2005     June/July 2005    Oct-Dec 2005   Jan-Mar 2006
Sample Set (Unique Visitors)  500K           1.5MM             1.8MM          1.9MM
# of Site for Sample          2              3                 3              3
800 x 600                     21%            16%               14%            12%
1024x768                      65%            67%               68%            69%
1280 x 1024                   10%            15%               16%            18%
1600 x 1200                                                    1.5%           1.5%
```

Comment: Yeah... well would it be more logical to develop web pages in high resolution for big displays then have another separate version for mobile devices and smaller displays? I mean could they run a test function to check the size of the screen and accordingly load the proper size of the website? I am not finding the logic in having it fixed at 1024x768px at all. Especially when talking about big companies that can afford developing different sizes for their websites.

Comment: +1 For the link and the table. You're right on that.

Comment: ANS: Well, taking your question above (in the comments section) into consideration, what are the cases that you need to open a website while doing other stuff at the same time? I mean, websites can be developed for a "football" field displays but the user can get to choose to zoom-out if needed. Whether the case is not true in the other way around when you see the size of text and elements quite small but you can't zoom-in as that might mess the resolution of the pictures inside.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a matter of good design choice. 1024 x 768 [seems](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) still to be a popular enough resolution; so web-designers, in order to ensure maximum reach, design their websites to be viewable (as intended) by people using resolutions of 1024 x 768 *and up*. In short, it's mostly done to ensure backward-compatibility and, as chirag points out, greater compatibility with mobile devices.

You should study the information on the page at the link above carefully. The shown trend hints greatly at current design etiquette, how this etiquette has evolved over the years, and why. It will also give you an idea of the thinking-styles of seasoned web-designers. After all, you don't want your website to be caught with undesired scrollbars sticking out the right ;-)

Comment: Indeed... Thanks for your further elaboration. [+1]